# Counting the pentagons and hexagons on the surface of a football (aka, soccer ball)

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, polygons

> For the Americans: I'm talking about soccer :-)
>
> As you might know, a football consists of a collection of regular pentagons and hexagons, but how much of which ones?

The construction is simple: for every pentagon, there's a hexagon at each side and for every hexagon, the polygons at its sides are altering between a pentagon and a hexagon.

Let's say we have the following numbers:

- $p$ : the number of points
- $s$ : the number of sides
- $u$ : the number of surfaces.

There is the well-known formula: $$p - s + u = 2$$

Let's now say:

- $v$ : the number of pentagons ("vijfhoek" in Dutch)
- $h$ : the number of hexagons

Then we know that: $$v + h = u$$

Every point is related to three segments and three surfaces, and every segment is related to two surfaces. But how to enter this in a formula to calculate the number of pentagons and hexagons? Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $v+h=u$. You also have $5v+6h=2s$ (each "side"/edge counts twice). You also have $5v+6h=3p$ (every "point"/vertex counts thrice). So:

$$\frac{1}{3}(5v+6h)-\frac{1}{2}(5v+6h)+(v+h)=2$$

i.e.

$$\frac{1}{6}v+0h=2$$

i.e. $v=12$. You must have $12$ pentagons. So, you can have plenty* of different "footballs", which only differ in the number of hexagons, the simplest one having no hexagons at all (i.e. a [dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)).

With your other conditions: if you say every hexagon is surrounded by $3$ pentagons and every pentagon is surrounded by $5$ hexagons you also have the relationship $3h=5v$ which on a football yields $h=20$.

---

*Note: this is an overstatement: if you want the football to be a [uniform polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron), then the dodecahedron and the F.A. football ([truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron)) seem to be the only choices.

Comment: $5v+6h=2p$ and $5v+6h=3p$, those are exactly the formulae I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a picture of the variant (in my opinion the most common), where the sides of the hexagons/pentagons are gotten by trisecting the sides of an icosahedron (aka BuckyBall). The edges of the circumscribed icosahedron show in this version. Look at the grey areas.

[image]

Comment: In this version the triangluar faces of an icosahedron become the hexagons, and the vertices of of the icosahedron become the pentagons. That should be enough to tally them :-)

Comment: This is indeed the kind of ball I'm talking about, but it does not answer my question.